# Simple vs Childish

Tags: icons, user-centered-design

What is the general rule of thumb regarding iconography style?
I'm more concerned regarding the feeling that some of my icons are too childish (using stick figures)... I'm afraid that the experience might not "enterprise like"...
What are the consensus around this? Are there papers regarding this point?
I feel that some icons such as a stick figure running for "rush my order" are more natural and understandable than others, but, some might see it as unprofessional...

Comment: It's really all about your brand. Grubhub (www.grubhub.com) has a very "childish" looking design choice, but that doesn't necessarily make them unprofessional. Same with Dropbox (www.dropbox).

Comment: There is no rule of thumb. It's impossible to say if your icons are childish or not without seeing them and the context they are placed in. As for 'enterprise like'--that isn't necessarily something anyone should aim for. Lots of enterprise software has truly awful UX (*cough* Peoplesoft *cough* Sharepoint *cough* etc.)

Comment: @DA01 You should probably get that coughing checked :^)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's probably better suited on [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @CodeMaverick I agree that the question as it stands should be migrated, but is it not possible to modify it so that it is suitable for UXSE? For example, what is the impact of iconography in relation to the overall UX or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion iconography style is not a stand-alone decision. You need to work it into all other facets of the visual element design (e.g. font, colours, layout, etc.) so that you can create a consistent look and feel (and hence user experience).

So the general rule of thumb is that if you are making this decision independent of other design element decisions then you are very likely to create an inconsistent look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

The professional look or childish look, is matter of how your rest of the content is presented. It sets up the theme and icons are part of the larger theme. The content writing style, tone, logo, etc all are considered for your icon style and they project collectively the impression of website.

Very basic thing is iconography must be understandable.
You icons must be consistent all throughout in terms of

- Style
- colors
- perspective

The icons designed can undergo a usability testing as well, which further ensures the icons are easily understood.